# add extra description field to file upload primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I use the primesfaces p:fileUpload tag, witch works fine. But I need to be able to ad a description to the files I upload. How can I do this?
I added a textfield on my page and assigned it to a bean property. But how Can I update it when pressing the primefaces upload button? (The fileUpload is ajax, so not the entire form is submitted. I don't want to submit the whole form because I don't want validation errors when uploading files)

Or should I need to use another tag (other library)?

Roel

Comment: Use process option of fileUpload.

Comment: there is no process attribute on <p:fileUpload

Comment: I see, this is available in primefaces3. I still use 2.2. But just did a test with 3. I processed filedesription inputfield. The value is update, but after the filupload event is triggerd. Soo too late